# Office with private/personal kitchen

Tags: word-request

At work, I have an office with private kitchen.

(the kitchen is a room for itself and the only entrance is from the office)

Questions:

What is such a kitchen called? Would you say "an office with private kitchen"? Or maybe "an office with personal kitchen"?

Comment: "a personal kitchen" would mean it's yours and no one else's... Since it's shared among your co-workers, I don't think "private" or "personal" fit.

Comment: Why do you assume it is shared.  Nothing in the question suggests that the kitchen is shared with co-workers.

Answer (score 1):

Private kitchen is fine, I'd also understand "personal kitchen".

I've never heard of such a thing.  Perhaps a "garden office (ie a outbuilding used as a office) could have one. So you might need to explain the context.

> Yes I converted my shed to an office.  I can work there and I have a private kitchen with a stove and coffee maker. It's great! I hardly have to see my family at all!.

Comment: Did you read the question? The kitchen is shared among the office workers.

Comment: Yes, I did read the question, thank you, and nowhere does it mention sharing.  Please read the question again. "Shared" is never mentioned in the question.  There is a comment mentioning sharing, but that is not by the OP.  The question says the kitchen is "private" and "the only entrance is through the office.  So it is **not** shared.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry about that. I guess there's no telling what OP meant.

Answer (score 1):

"Personal" and "private" probably don't fit if you share the kitchen with everyone else in the office.

But you could call it "the office kitchen". This makes it clear that the kitchen is part of the office and belongs with it. I.e., it shares a roof, and maybe a janitor or cleaner, and is for the use of the people who also have access to the office. In a similar vein you could say "company kitchen".

But maybe you don't need any modifier here. You could just say "an office with a kitchen". At least in my culture(s), that's clearly a kitchen that belongs with/to the office in the way you describe.